# iOS SDK can you mute or cancel incoming calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I found various threads here about how muting or canceling incoming calls (or messages) with the iOS SDK is not possible, due to the fact that Apple doesn't want an app to access system level settings. Well in fact not possible with the official tools, which means that if you somehow manage to do it, your app will not be accepted in the iTunes store.

Well I have been asked to assess the possibility of such an app that could do just that. Namely my client has seen these two apps

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lifesaver-distracted-driving/id874231222?mt=8
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/at-t-drivemode/id907208943?mt=8

And they are sure that an app, basically exactly like these (based on the functionality) can be made.

So here I am, asking, how did these two apps succeed at the impossible and also how did they manage to get those apps uploaded to the iTunes store, if muting your phone is not an Apple approved option? I am not really asking for source code, although I am certainly not rejecting examples, but moreso I am asking for pointers of what class or book or documentation do I have to look up to figure out if this is possible? Apples CTCall and CT* classes did not seem to help me much.

K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple added the CallKit framework in iOS 10 to allow app developers to do this sort of thing, among others.  For docs, see:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: How did you find a way to reject / hangup calls with Callkit? It doesn't look like it allows this sort of thing, does it?

Comment: Open the link, and Command-F for "Call Blocking & Identification".

Comment: how to application background work at time incoming call mute/ silent mode objective c

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to detect and block unwanted phone calls from iOS 10 and above.

See the [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) framework

> The CallKit framework (CallKit.framework) lets VoIP apps integrate
>   with the iPhone UI and give users a great experience. Use this
>   framework to let users view and answer incoming VoIP calls on the lock
>   screen and manage contacts from VoIP calls in the Phone app’s
>   Favorites and Recents views.
>
> CallKit also introduces app extensions that enable call blocking and
>   caller identification. You can create an app extension that can
>   associate a phone number with a name or tell the system when a number
>   should be blocked.